# regular expression to replace path variables in a URL

Tags: java, regex

I am using Java.
I want to check regular expression in a URL if it contains path variables like numeric ids and replace those with `*`.

I tried different patterns like `\/\d+.*`, but didn't get what I expected.

```
input url: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/123/456
expected output: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/*/*
```

another one:

```
input url: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/123/456/find
expected output: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask/*/*/find
```

What is the proper regular expression to replace the "/" with "/*"?

Comment: You'll need to give a specification of what you want rather than just a couple of examples. Is it always two components of the path?  ...

Comment: Can be many. It is just an example. I never said 2

Answer (score 2):

The regex to match path segments that are all digits:

```
/\d+(?=/|$)
```

To replace all with an asterisk:

```
String masked = url.replaceAll("/\\d+(?=/|$)", "/*");
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/22gBOIzMDQrfM5).

Breaking down the regex:

- `/\\d+` is a slash followed by digits
- `(?=/|$)` means the match must be followed by either a slash *or* end of input (`$`)

The replacement puts the slash that was matched back plus an asterisk.

Comment: That tool is awesome. I couldn't find such a good validator. Thanks your help